# Can Hasker's emergent dualism work (in principle) with a non-spatial mind without energy?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind

I know my question here is related : [According to Hasker's emergent dualism, why does the mind have to be spatial?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/56920/according-to-haskers-emergent-dualism-why-does-the-mind-have-to-be-spatial)

However, this is not a duplicate.  Can Hasker's emergent substance dualism approach work with the idea that the mind is a non-spatial entity? He assumes that the mind is spatial because of the relationship between brain matter and mind in his approach. However, it has been shown if the mind is spatial and contains energy, it cannot account for qualia.

So again, would Hasker's idea (substance mind emerged from matter) work with a non-spatial and non-energy mind?

Comment: "It has been shown if the mind is spatial and contains energy, it cannot account for qualia". It is generally doubtful that with entities as vague as mind and qualia anything can be definitively shown. If you mean Dilley's arguments they are hardly conclusive. His discussion of energy is largely moot, for example, mind can act causally in an energy neutral manner. It is also unclear what is left of "Hasker's idea" after making mind non-spatial. What exactly do you want to keep?

Comment: @Conifold That the mind is emergent from matter, but is a non-spatial entity.  I don't see why this is such a problem, could you explain?

Comment: It may not be a problem, one can think that space itself is emergent or relational. But Hasker's idea was to make dualism more palatable by eliminating mystical elements, and having non-spatial mind emerge from spatial matter hardly helps.

Comment: Popper's substance dualism has mind emerge from matter, and holds mind is non-spacial, but in time.  So it sounds like you want Popper's emergent dualism, rather than Hasker's.

Comment: I just read your link, where Dilley makes the claim "if the mind is spatial and contains energy, it cannot account for qualia".  Dilley has a variety of good critiques of Hasker, but this one, which he itemizes as point 3 of his list, is the weakest.  He is assuming that modal arguments against materialism are valid, and matter is simply incapable of supporting qualia.  If this is true, then making mind spacial and energy dependent is to make it material, and incapable of supporting qualia.  However, note that the conclusion he drew, HE ALSO ASSUMES!  This argument is circular in his paper.

Comment: @Dcleve "He is assuming that modal arguments against materialism are valid, and matter is simply incapable of supporting qualia." Don't all dualists assume this? Isn't this the reason for dualism in the first place?

Comment: @Noah, Hasker does not accept them, nor does Popper.  Both treat mind as an emergent "phase change" of matter.

Comment: @Dcleve what about Eccles and/or Swinburne?

Comment: @Noah I have a review of Swinburne here:  https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R18J8OJA7QPLKX/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=0199662576 Modal arguments do not show up in this book at least.  Here is a reveiw of Moreland -- his Chapter 4 was a series of modal arguments, and I criticize them in the review:  https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R1258UWL7YD47C?ref=pf_vv_at_pdctrvw_srp  Eccles was a scientist not philosopher, he did not depend on modal arguments.

Comment: @Dcleve I found a paper on Eccles's ideas on substance dualism http://www.theosophy-nw.org/theosnw/science/prat-bra.htm. It's the 3rd paragraph where it describes the mind as a different field. Would this be the phase change of matter that popper has?

Comment: Eccles uses Popper's 3 worlds ontology.  Matter is in world 1, Mind is resident in world 2, ideas in world 3.  Popper is a non-spiritual dualist, he thought mind was emergent from matter, world 1 preceeded world 2.  Eccles is a spiritual dualist, he considers world 2 to pre-exist world 1, and souls to pre-exist bodies.

Comment: Sheldrake is an idealist, not a dualist, he thinks all of apparent reality is created by morphic fileds of various types.   Your writer is trying to link Eccles and Sheldrake together into a support for a theosophical worldview -- but neither of them were theosophists, and they did not share much in the way of common beliefs.

Comment: @Dcleve If one holds Eccles's view (spiritual dualist worlds ontology) does that mean that they accept the Modal arguments?

Comment: I am a spiritual dualist and I do not accept the modal arguments.  That mental is not physical -- is for me an empirical obseration, not a modal derivation.  Maybe our world could have been different (IE reject modal logic argument), but in THIS world, mental and physical are different.

Comment: @Dcleve do you think the mind is spatial?

Comment: No.  I do divide "mind" between unconsciouisness, which is primarily material processing, and consciousness, which is primarily spiritual.  Spirits interact with material space.  Sometimes that interaction can be a locational tie -- our souls are tied to our bodies most of the time while we are alive.  Not all spirit is conscious -- for example the interaction principles operate unconsciously.

Comment: @Dcleve So the spirits themselves are spatial entities correct?